# How do I filter to match or exclude certain fields in Octave?

Tags: linux, octave

How do I filter to match or exclude certain fields in Octave?

Using Octave 3.0.5 on CentOS 5.8, I need to filter rows out of a larger matrix for some various analyses.

For example, I have an array that looks like this:

```
A = { [ 0, 5, 32 ],
      [ 0, 3, 2  ],
      [ 1, 4, 13 ],
      [ 1, 2, 32 ],
      [ 2, 7, 99 ],
      [ 2, 0, 42 ] };
```

Now I need to be able to extract all rows where the first value is equal to 1, or maybe where the second value is greater than 3, etc. I've tried reading the documentation and searching for examples, but I'm just not seeing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cellfun` to go through the cell array and get an index (binary):

```
octave> cellfun (@(x) x(1) == 1 || x(2) > 3, A)
ans =

   1
   0
   1
   1
   1
   0
```

Using your example:

```
octave> A(cellfun (@(x) x(1) == 1 || x(2) > 3, A))
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

      0    5   32

  [2,1] =

      1    4   13

  [3,1] =

      1    2   32

  [4,1] =

      2    7   99

}
```

An alternative which may be faster is to ditch the cell array completely and use a matrix instead (as long as each cell in the cell array have the same size, a matrix makes a lot more sense, even if you need to create a multi-dimensional matrix). That's likely to be much faster and simpler to read:

```
octave> B = cell2mat (A);
octave> B(B(:,1) == 1 | B(:,2) > 3, :)
ans =

    0    5   32
    1    4   13
    1    2   32
    2    7   99
```